# laravel + inertia.js + typescript + react + Material UI で、F5キーで画面ロードするとエラー(HTTP ERROR 500)になる場合があります。

Tags: laravel, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

laravel + inertia.js + typescript + react + Material UI で、F5キーで画面ロードするとエラー(HTTP ERROR 500)になる場合があります。
[image: エラー]

Code splittingでうまくいっていないと思いますが、エラーになる場合とエラーにならない場合の基準がわかりません。
https://inertiajs.com/code-splitting

何かご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけると嬉しいです。

※同様の質問をteratailでも投稿しています。
https://teratail.com/questions/qbr5hkbpqryt9q